# Order a column by pair of values

Tags: sql, vertica

I have 2 simple columns:
one column is simply an ID column and the other column is some sort of boolean type column.

```
ID   V
0    1
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    1
5    0
```

I want to order the rows by pair of values (0,1) of column V
(while still keeping the ID as minimal as possible):

```
ID   V
1    0
0    1
2    0
3    1
5    0
4    1
```

How do I do that ?

Comment: What are the rules for ordering, what's *pair of values*?

Answer (score 3):

Seems you want get rows for 0 and 1 in turn:

```
select id, v
from tab
order by
   row_number() 
   over (partition by v
         order by id)
  ,v
```